# How to modify an object with an array of observables?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I feel like this should be simpler than I'm making it! Here's a jsbin with what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/sasamaf/1/edit?js,console

I have arrays of strings representing "category" and "thing".  I ultimately want to create an array of `Category` items, each of which has a things property that is an array of `Thing` items. The `Thing` items each come from a service method which returns an Observable.

```
class ThingService {
    getThing(name: string): Rx.Observable<Thing> {
        var thing = new Thing();
        thing.name = name;
        thing.data = "data for " + name;
        return Rx.Observable.of(thing);
    } 
}

class Category {
    name: string;
    things: Thing[];
}

class Thing {
    name: string;
    data: string;
}
```

Given arrays of category names and thing names, how can I create a function that returns a `Observable<Category[]>` that has its thing arrays filled out?

```
category_names = [ "foo", "bar" ];
things_per_category = [ "Hello", "World" ];
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
getCategories(): Rx.Observable<any> {
    return Rx.Observable.from(this.category_names
                .map(n => {
                    var category = new Category();
                    category.name = n;
                    return category;
                })
            )
            .flatMap(cat => {
                // For this category, create the array of things and
                // attach them to the "things" property of the category

                var ary_of_thing_observables = this.things_per_category.map(thing_name => {
                    console.log("getting thing " + thing_name + " for category " + cat.name)
                    return this.service.getThing(thing_name);
                })

                // ??? How to get from the Observable<Thing> to 
                // adding a Thing to the "things" array?

                return Rx.Observable.of("???");
            })         
    }
}
```

I ultimately want the returned observable to resolve to this:

```
[
    { 
        name: 'Foo',
        things: [
            { name: 'Hello', data: 'data for Hello' },
            { name: 'World', data: 'data for World' }
        ]
    },
    { 
        name: 'Bar',
        things: [
            { name: 'Hello', data: 'data for Hello' },
            { name: 'World', data: 'data for World' }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I iterate over my array, create my things, and attach them to each category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to obtain `Thing[]` from `Observable<Thing>[]` and you can then use `map` to assign the `Thing[]` value to the category and return the category itself.

And to have the composed observable emit an array of categories, you can use `toArray`:

```
.flatMap(cat => {
  var ary_of_thing_observables = things_per_category.map(thing_name => {
    console.log("getting thing " + thing_name + " for category " + cat.name);
    return getThing(thing_name);
  });
  return Rx.Observable
    .forkJoin(ary_of_thing_observables)
    .map(things => {
      cat.things = things;
      return cat;
    });
})
.toArray();
```

Comment: Ah, these things always seem so clear after someone points out a solution!  `forkJoin` is perfect here.  Thanks!